# string or binary data would be truncated. the statement has been terminated. in c#

Tags: sql, aspnetdb

```
MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream();
MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream();

customer_pic_1.Image.Save(ms1,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
byte[] img_arr1 = new byte[ms1.Length];
ms1.Read(img_arr1,0,img_arr1.Length);

//ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
//return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img_arr1, typeof(byte[]));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", name_txt.Text );
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", designation_txt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", mobile_txt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", mail_txt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e", image_path_txt.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f", img_arr1);

int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

if (result > 0)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Ur Data Inserted Successfully....$");
}
else
{
   MessageBox.Show("Sorry Ur data inserting Fail...!");
}

conx.Close();
```

While inserting the image I get an error:

> string or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.

Please help for me .....

I tried in both i.e. in backend for image column image varbinary also I had used.....it is not working..........

Comment: The error is pretty clear: one of the values you provide (`@a` through `@e`) is longer than what it's column in SQL Server is defined at. Check your column definitions against the values you're trying to store - at least one will be too long

Answer (score 1):

The maximal length of the target column is shorter than the value you try to insert. Try editing the table's column for that.

And additionally please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Welcome to SO! :)